# msgasserted linker errors on Mongo C++ Drivers on MacOSX 10.10.3 Yosemite

Tags: c++, mongodb, boost

I am having some issues compiling codes using mongo C++ drivers on MacOSX
It is part of a larger project that is controlled using CMake

Below are the errors I am facing:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "mongo::msgasserted(int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
  mongo::BSONObj::_assertInvalid() const in libworker.a(mongo_handler.cpp.o)
  mongo::BSONElement::chk(int) const in libworker.a(mongo_handler.cpp.o)
 "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,       std::__1::allocator<char> > mongo::integerToHex<int>(int)", referenced from:
  mongo::BSONObj::_assertInvalid() const in libworker.a(mongo_handler.cpp.o)
 "mongo::causedBy(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
  mongo::DBException::addContext(std::__1::basic_string<char,  std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in   libworker.a(mongo_handler.cpp.o)
 "mongo::uasserted(int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
  mongo::BSONArrayBuilder::fill(mongo::StringData const&) in libworker.a(mongo_handler.cpp.o)
  mongo::BSONElement::toString(mongo::StringBuilderImpl<mongo::TrivialAllocator>&, bool, bool, int) const in libworker.a(mongo_handler.cpp.o)
 "mongo::UserException::appendPrefix(std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) const", referenced from:
  vtable for mongo::ConnectException in libworker.a(mongo_handler.cpp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [bin/test/worker/test_dbmanager] Error 1
make[1]: *** [test/worker/CMakeFiles/test_dbmanager.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Installation of Dependencies:

1) boost libraries 1.57 using brew

2) scons options used: (pulled the latest version of the drivers on 26compat branch. Target MongoDB version 2.6.5

```
sudo apt-get install scons
git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver.git

#checkout the stable 2.6 drivers
cd mongo-cxx-driver
git checkout 26compat

#compile the drivers
sudo scons --full --use-system-boost --sharedclient install-mongoclient
```

3) Snippet of code I am using and caused the problem

```
#include <mongo/client/dbclient.h>
//... some class definitions and declarations
mongo::DBClientConnection m_connection;
void MongoRequestHandler::connect(const std::string& host_and_port) {
    m_connection.connect(host_and_port);
}
```

4) code compiles perfectly fine on Linux Ubuntu 14.04

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT

I have attached the link options as suggested:

```
-fPIC -msse3 -std=c++11 -O3 -DNDEBUG -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-    headerpad_max_install_names      CMakeFiles/test_dbmanager.dir/test_dbmanager.cpp.o  -o ../../bin/test/worker/test_dbmanager  ../../lib/libworker.a   ../../lib/libengine.dylib ../../lib/libutls.a ../../lib/libimageutls.a /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpng.dylib   /usr/lib/libz.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dylib   /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib  /usr/local/lib/libmongoclient.dylib ../../lib/libcompression.a ../../lib/libutls.a ../../lib/libaffpts.a /usr/local/Cellar/flann/1.8.4/lib/libflann.dylib /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpng.dylib /usr/lib/libz.dylib ../../lib/libmessage.a -lthrift /usr/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmongoclient.dylib
```

EDIT

Issue fixed,

It was due to incorrect scons flags being passed to the compilation. Scons presumes 10.6 as the minimum version for osx, which builds the library on libstdc++, setting --osx-version-min=10.10, will force libc++ to be used instead which is the default lib linked on 10.10.

Comment: Can you post the link line for the target bin/test/worker/test_dbmanager?

Comment: I have a suspicion that the driver is building against libstdc++ and your application is building against libc++. Can you try re-building the driver with the --osx-version-min=10.10 flag? That should let it automatically use libc++.

Comment: apparently your suspicion is right,

Comment: apparently your suspicion is right, 

running otool -L libmongoclient.dylib shows that it was linked against libstdc++, I have recompiled it to link to libc++ and it seems fine now. Thank you for the the help!

Comment: Glad to hear it is working for you now.